# UART program for PIC18f65k40

Tags: pic

I'm trying to program my MCU in mickroc still I do not get a output.

Is there any difference between PIC18f65k40 and PIC18f65k22 in terms of initiating uart transmission? Whether there is any need to initiate or disable any special registers in PIC18f65k40?

In mikroc software there present a library for uart so I just copied the program from mickroe website and add my transmitter and receiver pins(`RX4PPS = 0x11;` and   `TX4PPS = 0x10;`)in program by configuring portc as output but my circuit does not work.

```
 char i ;
 void main()
 {
   TRISC  = 0b00000000;// making port as output
   RX4PPS = 0x11;
   TX4PPS = 0x10;
   UART4_Init(9600);            // Initialize USART module
                              // (8 bit, 9600 baud rate, no parity bit...)
   delay_ms(500);
   UART4_Write_Text("Hello world!");
   UART4_Write(13);      // Start a new line
   UART4_Write(10);
   UART4_Write_Text("PIC18F65K40 UART example");
   UART4_Write(13);     // Start a new line
   UART4_Write(10);
   while (1) {
     if (UART4_Data_Ready()) { // If data has been received
       i = UART4_Read();       // read it
       UART4_Write(i);         // and send it back
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I added my code in previous post, it is just copied from mickroe examples. This is what i tried.

Answer (score 1):

The PIC18F65k22 has only 2 UARTs and you are working with UART4. I guess the library don't support the controller. Better write the code on your own. There are some examples in the datasheet.

Comment: sir, i'm doing the program in PIC18F65K40, there are 5 UARTs in this MCU. To check the code working fine, i am simulating the code by changing UART4 as UART1 in proteus with PIC18F65K22 because i don't have PIC18F65K40 in proteus. Sorry if i am unclear.